# Scheduling in while loop that runs forever

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I have a while loop which will run forever as I need. Now I want to run scheduler in that loop and I want to run some command after every hour in that loop. Is this possible ? Current code . I dont want to use sleep since I want to continuously check for other codes so don't suggest `SLEEP ,JAVASCRIPT & CONJOBS`

```
<?php
set_timelimit(0);

while(true)
{
  getChat();

 //Here I want to run a function after every hour. How do I do it ?
 if(everyhour)
 {
      runthisfunction()
 }


}
```

Comment: you can use cronjob for this.

Comment: Please have a look at Cronjobs. (Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: Please use relevant tags.

Comment: I know about cron jobs. But if I run through cron job.. this script will be killed since I can login into a script at once only.

Comment: I dont think you have thought through your application design very well ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley : There is a solution of every problem. I hope you understand. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do something like:

```
if(date('i') == '00'){
    //do code
}
```

Though you'll likely need to use something like flush() to get any output to show up.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to call a *PHP* script at certain intervals.

**OR**

Try scheduled tasks through [CronJobs](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml).

Also have a look through this article to run *PHP* scripts through [Cron](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/).

So basically what you will have to do is create the script you want to run via *PHP* and using the above articles create a *Cron* for the specific interval.

Comment: this is gonna get downvotes ... just a heads up .. since he specifically mentions cronjobs (regardless of it being the "right" answer)  ... (or maybe not ... nice)

Comment: Already mentioned that I dont want to use cronjobs. Well, Rechard already gave the solution.